# Error: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length while creating multiple variables in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to create multiple columns in `data.table` in one command since logic is simple. I have column of starting values `a0` and need to create time evolution by simply adding constant to next column.

Here is reproducible example

```
dt <- data.table(a0 = c(0.3, 0.34, 0.45, 0.6, 0.37, 0.444))

dt[, paste0('a', 1:5) := a0 + 1:5 / 4]
```

I would expect this produces columns a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 by simply adding 1/4 to each next column, instead getting warning and incorrect result

```
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

dt
    a0    a1    a2    a3    a4    a5
1: 0.300 0.550 0.550 0.550 0.550 0.550
2: 0.340 0.840 0.840 0.840 0.840 0.840
3: 0.450 1.200 1.200 1.200 1.200 1.200
4: 0.600 1.600 1.600 1.600 1.600 1.600
5: 0.370 1.620 1.620 1.620 1.620 1.620
6: 0.444 0.694 0.694 0.694 0.694 0.694
```

It looks R is calculating in a wrong dimension. Tried to add list `dt[, paste0('a', 1:5) := list(a0 + 1:5 / 4)]`, but without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the warning because `length(dt$a0)` is 6 whereas `length(1:5)` is 5.

```
dt$a0 + 1:5
#[1] 1.300 2.340 3.450 4.600 5.370 1.444
```

> Warning message:
>   In dt$a0 + 1:5 :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Here the first value of `1:5` is recycled and added to `dt$a0[6]`.

You cannot reference the previous column directly like that. If you want to add new columns based on previous columns value in this case you can do something like

```
library(data.table)
n <- 5
dt[, paste0('a', seq_len(n)) := lapply(seq_len(n)/4, function(x) x + a0)]

dt
#      a0    a1    a2    a3    a4    a5
#1: 0.300 0.550 0.800 1.050 1.300 1.550
#2: 0.340 0.590 0.840 1.090 1.340 1.590
#3: 0.450 0.700 0.950 1.200 1.450 1.700
#4: 0.600 0.850 1.100 1.350 1.600 1.850
#5: 0.370 0.620 0.870 1.120 1.370 1.620
#6: 0.444 0.694 0.944 1.194 1.444 1.694
```

Comment: modifying ```lapply(seq_len(5), function(x) a0 + x/4)``` does what I wanted

Comment: @user2761282 Updated the answer. I misunderstood what you needed earlier.